# Создание label в цикле for

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Цель**: При нажатии на кнопку открывается новое окно, в котором с помощью **Label** и **for** будет выводится список (каждый элемент выводится с новой строки или **Label**).

**Проблема**: **Label** выводит последний элемент списка

```py
def dispaly_contact():
    window = Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry('350x500')
    address_book_file = open("address_book_file", "rb")
    is_file_empty = os.path.getsize("address_book_file") == 0
    if not is_file_empty:
        list_contacts = pickle.load(address_book_file)
        for each_contact in list_contacts:
            lbl = Label(window, text=each_contact).place(x=5, y=5)
    else:
        print("У вас нет контактов в книге")
        return
    address_book_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все `Label` выводятся в одно и то же место (с помощью `place(x=5, y=5)`), каждый следующий поверх предыдущего, поэтому вы видите только последний добавленный `Label`.

Проще всего исправить заменив `place` на `pack` или `grid` (без параметров они автоматически располагают каждый следующий элемент ниже предыдущего):

```
Label(window, text=each_contact).grid(sticky=W)  # sticky=W нужно для выравнивания по левому краю (W = West, запад)
```

Также можно заменить несколько `Label` на один `Listbox`.

```
listbox = Listbox(window)
listbox.pack()
for each_contact in list_contacts:
    listbox.insert(END, each_contact)
```